# jQuery Mobile with PhoneGap on iPhone - Panels move across in sections

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

Using jQuery mobile panel animations with PhoneGap, on the iPhone, the animation appears to happen in sections. Either the top half moves first and then the second half, or items with text move at a different time to everything else. Works fine on Android.

Anyone come across this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved this by using xCode to build the iPhone version rather than using PhoneGap. Looks like a PhoneGap issue.